# Install gRPC library in alpine docker container

Tags: docker, grpc, alpine-linux

I want to install gRPC cpp library inside alpine docker container. 
[This](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/grpc) is where I find the gRPC package available inside alpine:edge. However when I tried to do

```
apk update && apk add --no-cache grpc
```

from `alpine:edge`, but it gives me:

> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
>    grpc (missing):
>      required by: world[grpc]

Am I missing any step?

Comment: Can you provide the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `grpc` package resides in the `testing` repository of the `edge`  branch.
Use apk's `--repository` option for specifying the repository to pull from:

```
apk update && apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/
alpine/edge/testing
```

Note, the `edge` branch, and more so `testing` repositories, are considered experimental, so use them with care.

Answer (score 7):

Full command

```
apk update && apk add --no-cache --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing grpcurl
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It could be, but honestly, that was the only thing I searched for. A straightforward command with the command to run. It's self-explanatory if one takes time to read arguments and their values.